# Is there a difference between consuming (BMR) calories and burning n calories vs. consuming (BMR-n) calories?

Tags: calories, bmr

I am morbidly obese based on my BMI (41-ish% body fat). I want to lose 1lb/week, which I believe equates to a 500 Calorie deficit/day. My BMR is 2660.

Is there a difference in the context of weight-loss between consuming 2160 Calories with no additional exercise, and consuming 2660 Calories and additional exercise to burn 500 Calories?

Math-wise I believe they are equivalent, however I'm not sure if there are any bodily functional differences between the two of them.

Comment: http://www.barbellmedicine.com/potpourri/584/

Comment: You are confusing bmr with tdee(total daily energy expenditure). Bmr is what you burn if you are in a coma lying in bed. Tdee is your burn going about your daily life. In answer to your question yes the math is all the same

Comment: @yisrael I figured I'd use BMR as a worst-case scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is. Benefits of exercises are not only limited to instant energy ependiture but also recovery energy consumption after exercise (which will increase your total energy expenditure). In addition, since you will gain more muscle with exercise it will also increase BMR. It is a win win sutiation :-)